# I dont understand what plt.show()...does

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am starting to learn about plotting and have a question about what plt.show() does.

I get the definition "The show() function in pyplot module of matplotlib library is used to display all figures", but can never find what figures this refers to. The two examples I looked at:

```
# sample code 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [16, 4, 1, 8])  
plt.show()  


# Implementation of matplotlib function 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure() 
x = np.arange(20) / 50
y = (x + 0.1)*2
  
val1 = [True, False] * 10
val2 = [False, True] * 10
  
plt.errorbar(x, y,  
xerr = 0.1,  
xlolims = True,  
label ='Line 1') 
  
y = (x + 0.3)*3
  
plt.errorbar(x + 0.6, y,  
xerr = 0.1, 
xuplims = val1, 
xlolims = val2, 
label ='Line 2') 
  
y = (x + 0.6)*4
plt.errorbar(x + 1.2, y, 
xerr = 0.1,  
xuplims = True, 
label ='Line 3') 
  
plt.legend() 
  
fig.suptitle('matplotlib.pyplot.show() Example') 
plt.show()
```

Seem to be not very good example, because when I comment out the plt.show() line and execute the code, it displays exactly the same result as before, when plt.show() was not commented out.

Can someone explain to me (as if I were a fourth grader) what the purpose of plt.show() is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422714/when-is-plt-show-required-to-show-a-plot-and-when-is-it-not

Answer (score 0):

In short: there isn't one way of plotting a graph in Matplotlib, but two. And you're mixing them together.

The first way is a method based approach, that way uses pyplot. Most of your code is like that. That code displays immediately. Need proof? Comment out every line but the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
    
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [16, 4, 1, 8])
```

And you'll see that it displays just fine.

But, as I mentioned, you're mixing in some code from the object oriented (OO) approach. OO code in matplotlib puts out the product as a figure object which may or may not have subfigures. OO code in matplotlib starts with setting up the figure object, which you also did with `fig = plt.figure()`. It calls that object with plt.show(), which you also did. But almost the rest of your code is method based.

Almost all. The one other line of OO code is this:

```
fig.suptitle('matplotlib.pyplot.show() Example')
```

Need proof? Take out `fig = plt.figure()` where the object is instantiated.

You need all three parts -- setting up the object, giving it something to do, and telling it to display.

I'm guessing at this point you're thinking that still doesn't explain why the error bar plot displays when you take out the last `plt.show()` since you can see it right in the jupyter notebook, right? But if you were try that in ipython, you would find it won't display because didn't tell it to. Here the difference is jupyter notebook will often give you an output where otherwise you wouldn't get one. It does that as a matter of convenience.

So, basically, you're making an otherwise empty object that contains just the title and plotting over that a bunch of immediately displayed plots that line up on top. And something similar to last line gets executed because that just the way a jupyter notebook works.