# Batch plotting in PyTorch using Matplotlib isn't working

Tags: matplotlib, pytorch, tensor, image-classification

I am trying to plot a batch of image (batch size 128) in pytorch using make_grid function in my local machine. But when I call the function its like the calling block never compile. I have waited for long but the asteric sign of compiling never be gone.[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJldo.jpg)

The defined function:

```
from torchvision.utils import make_grid

def show_batch(dl):
    for images, labels in dl:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
        ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.imshow(make_grid(images, nrow=16).permute(1, 2, 0))
        break
```

Calling the function

```
show_batch(val_dl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `plt.show()` after `ax.imshow()` ([this answer will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422714/when-is-plt-show-required-to-show-a-plot-and-when-is-it-not)), or replace `break` to `time.sleep(10)`